# increase (or decrease) all javascript indexes by a number

Tags: javascript

I have an array like so:

```js
array = [1,2,3,4]
console.dir(array)
```

In which the index positions would be

```
array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2, array[2] = 3, array[3] = 4.
```

What I'd like to do is shift all the indexes up by 2, without changing the values to get:

```
array[2] = 0, array[3] = 1, array[4] = 2, array[5] = 3
```

I'm adding my solution just in case there isn't a better option, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's a one-liner to do it. Ideally, that updates the original array rather than inputting it into a new one.

Comment: Your solution creates a new array, but the impression from the question is you want to use the same array. Which is it? *(Not my downvote on the answer)*

Comment: I guess I'm not too fussed by which, with a slight preference to updating the original array. I'll update my answer to clarify my preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I wouldn't be surprised if there's a one-liner to do it. Ideally, that updates the original array rather than inputting it into a new one.

There *is* a one-liner, but I'm not saying I'd use it in real code, not least because of the abuse of the comma operator: :-)

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4];

Object.keys(array).reverse().forEach(key => (array[+key+2] = array[key], delete array[key]));

console.log(array);
```

Or you said you're not that fussed about whether you get a new array; you can get a one-liner by (ab)using `reduce` and the comma operator:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4];

const new_array = array.reduce((a, e, i) => (a[i+2] = e, a), []);

console.log(new_array);
```

Boring person that I am, I'd probably just use a loop:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4];

for (let n = array.length - 1; n >= 0; --n) {
  array[n+2] = array[n];
  delete array[n];
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the variety of suggestions - I hadn't thought about looping backwards through the array at all! I think the first solution is actually more accessible than one might initially think when reading it.

Comment: @itHaffens: I should have mentioned: If you're *decreasing* the indexes, naturally you have to loop the other way...

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version with array concatenation (assuming you're ok with having `undefined` in the first places since that's what you do in your example)

```js
array = [0,1,2,3];
array2 = [undefined, undefined];

array = array2.concat(array);

console.dir(array);
```

Comment: I like the legibility of this - and could be reduced to a cheeky one liner: array = [undefined,undefined].concat(array).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:-

```js
array = [0,1,2,3]
new_array = [];
array.forEach(function(element,index){
  new_array[index+2]=element
});
array = new_array;
console.dir(array);
```

Comment: did you checked your `console.log()` output:- it's undefined man

Comment: @AlivetoDie: That's just how this console shows the missing entries in sparse arrays.

Comment: @AlivetoDie - My understanding is with T.J. Crowder's - if there's no value for array[0] and array[1] then it has to be "undefined" - right?

Comment: does javascript keeps index in array ?